# An operating System wasn't found, try disconnecting any drive,

Tags: laptop-repair

An operating System wasn't found, try disconnecting any drive, that didn't contain an operating system, click ctrol/alt/delete

bitlocker was loaded on but the user already had PGP software

suggestions

Answer (score 0):

going to your BIOS when you launch your computer. Go to boot and set up the boot priority so your device is first. Make sure you don't have any USB flash drives when booting the computer that can also screw it up. Make sure you don't have any optical media in the disk drive or anything like that. You can still keep the keyboard and mouse inside your computer. Just not any storage device other than your hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

My second solution is, make sure that your disk or USB flash drive Works. You can't touch this by going on your computer onto a VirtualBox if you have the program installed, put the media in your computer and try launching it through VirtualBox if it doesn't work then maybe your media wasn't burned correctly.